# Should I Shutdown Scheduler at Servlet's destroy() Method?

Tags: java, servlets, quartz-scheduler

There is a startup servlet that initialises Quartz Scheduler in the init() method and shut down the scheduler at destroy() method. I understand that Servlet itself is an object and will be GC collected at a unknown interval. If a shut down of Quartz Scheduler is placed in the destroy() method, I am expecting the scheduler to be restarted each time the servlet is GC collected. If the process of the destroy and start skipped the exact timing where I am expecting quartz to run a thread, I probably will have trouble. Am I right in this assumption?

Note: I noted that there is a context listener in the quartz library to shut down quartz when the application is out of service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Servlet specification does allow containers to unload Servlets at any point although they don't have to do this (Tomcat doesn't for example). You are unlikely to hit a problem but if Quartz is used by components other than the Servlet that starts it them it really belongs to the application not the Servlet and should be configured at that level.

Generally, it is better to start and stop Quartz with a ServletContextListener than with a Servlet.

Comment: THanks for the reply. Although tomcat doesn't unload/loads servlets, but does GC recollect it? According to the GC behavior, it will recollect the servlet if it decides to, especially if the servlet like mine are not holding on any processes after the start up initialisation. My concern is whether quartz will be restart whenever GC recollect that servlet since destroy() will be called if GC decided to recollect the servlet.

Comment: Tomcat is holding a reference to the Servlet so it can't be GC'd unless Tomcat releases it (which it doesn't until the application is unloaded).